# Order of execution in Kotlin String template

Tags: string, templates, kotlin

This is a pretty silly question, but here goes:

```
var i = 0
var str = "this is ${i++}, ${i++} and ${i++}"
```

Am I guaranteed to get a string `this is 0, 1, 2` here? In other words: is the execution of variables in a String template in Kotlin deterministic?

Comment: Have you tried it? When I execute it, I always get *"this is 0, 1 and 2"* as output...

Comment: It's one thing to try something and another to convince yourself that it will _always_ work :). But yes, I tried it for a couple of scenarios.

Comment: Sure, I know that difference ;-) I could also have asked: *Have you tested it with 100% coverage*, but it appeared obvious, you hadn't ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That will translate to calling `append` for each interpolation parameter in order. So the order is guaranteed.